# Content-Length header already present

Tags: java, android, httpclient

I am using the Apache HttpClient (4.1) included in Android to execute a HttpPut.  I have verified that I only have 1 content-length header.  However, every time I send the request, I get a protocol exception about the Content-Length header already specified.

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
putMethod = new HttpPut(url + encodedFileName);
putMethod.addHeader(..)  //<-once for each header
putMethod.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(data));
client.execute(putMethod);  //throws Exception
```

Caused by: org.apache.http.ProtocolException: Content-Length header already present
     at org.apache.http.protocol.RequestContent.process(RequestContent.java:70)
     at org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpProcessor.process(BasicHttpProcessor.java:290)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I've not used HttpClient myself, but I suspect that the problem is that `putMethod.setEntity(...)` is implicitly supplying a content length and you are also setting it explicitly via one of the `putMethod.addHeader(...)` calls.

Comment: Exactly. You never have to set Content-Length yourself in Java unless you are using a plain Socket.

Comment: @EJP - or the java.net URLConnection classes.

Comment: No, they do it for you. You only have to set it if you *aren't* using those.

Comment: @EJP - incorrect.  With an HttpURLConnection, the **only** way to create an HTTP request with a body is for the application to call `getOutput()` and write to the resulting `OutputStream`.  The implementation only knows how many bytes of content it is sending when the application closes the stream.  By then it is to late to go back and write a "content-length" in the request header.

Comment: Obviously you've never tried it. HttpURLConnection provides a ByteArrayOutputStream as he output stream, so it can do exactly that. Except in the case when you are in chunked transfer mode when it doesn't need to.

Comment: @EJP - I use HttpURLConnection all the time.  But I've always gone on what I've understood the javadoc to mean.

Comment: Fair enough, but the Javadoc doesn't say it can't build its own Content-Length header, and it also says 'In the common case, all of the pre-connection parameters and general request properties can be ignored: the pre-connection parameters and request properties default to sensible values. For most clients of this interface, there are only two interesting methods ...'

Comment: Thanks for the help guys.  I found the source for 4.1 and of course you are right.  However, it seems you either could or should in 3.x.  Not sure which...

Comment: Btw - I was able to verify this by setting a request interceptor (at the end) and looking at the modified request.  It shows the Content-Length already set.

Comment: I tried removing the header. But now getting the error "Length Required " from my api. What could be the possible reason

Comment: @AjithMemana - I expect that is because your code is materially different to the code in this question.

Answer (score 46):

As pointed out by igor.zh, this problem can occur if using Spring's HttpComponentsMessageSender class. To be more precise though, this is only a problem if you are passing your own instance of HttpClient into the HttpComponentsMessageSender constructor - the issue is handled automatically otherwise.

As of spring-ws 2.1.4, the HttpComponentsMessageSender.RemoveSoapHeadersInterceptor subclass that is used in the default constructor was made public to address this issue (see https://jira.spring.io/browse/SWS-835) and so can be used in your own HttpClient instances instead of writing your own class to do it. It also clears the HTTP.TRANSFER_ENCODING header.

Use the HttpClientBuilder.addInterceptorFirst method to inject this interceptor into your own HttpClient instance. Example below using XML bean wiring. If anybody knows a more concise way of constructing the HttpClient instance (aside from writing a factory bean class), I'm all ears!

```
<bean id="httpClientBuilder" class="org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder" factory-method="create"/>

<bean id="interceptedHttpClientBuilder" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject" ref="httpClientBuilder" />
    <property name="targetMethod" value="addInterceptorFirst"> </property>
    <property name="arguments">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpComponentsMessageSender.RemoveSoapHeadersInterceptor"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="httpClient" factory-bean="interceptedHttpClientBuilder" factory-method="build" />

<bean id="webServiceTemplate" class="org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="messageFactory"/>
    <property name="messageSender">
        <bean class="org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpComponentsMessageSender">
            <property name="httpClient" ref="httpClient"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Alternatively, if you can, just allow HttpComponentsMessageSender to construct its own HttpClient instance rather than passing one to it. Minor note on this: as of spring-ws 2.2.0-RELEASE, the default constructor for HttpComponentsMessageSender continues to use the DefaultHttpClient class, which is now deprecated. Hopefully this will be addressed in a future release.

Answer (score 15):

That happens to me when I used http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/apidocs/org/springframework/ws/transport/http/HttpComponentsMessageSender.html as a Spring WebService Message Sender. In that case the stuff like HttpPut or HttpRequest are not easily accessible, so, building HttpClient with HttpClientBuilder, I ended up inserting a HttpRequestInterceptor in front of the culprit RequestContent :

```
private static class ContentLengthHeaderRemover implements HttpRequestInterceptor{
    @Override
    public void process(HttpRequest request, HttpContext context) throws HttpException, IOException {
        request.removeHeaders(HTTP.CONTENT_LEN);// fighting org.apache.http.protocol.RequestContent's ProtocolException("Content-Length header already present");
    }
}
...
    HttpClientBuilder httpClientBuilder = HttpClients.custom();
    httpClientBuilder.addInterceptorFirst(new CcontentLengthHeaderRemover());
```

Answer (score 10):

[John Rix's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28986513/446921) has the right idea. Here's how you do it with plain java:

```
HttpClient client = HttpClients.custom()
    .addInterceptorFirst(new RemoveSoapHeadersInterceptor())
    .build();
```

Comment: You have to import that interceptor class 
`import org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpComponentsMessageSender.RemoveSoapHeadersInterceptor;`

Answer (score 1):

If you checkout http://docjar.org/docs/api/org/apache/http/protocol/RequestContent.html you'll notice that it throws that exception if you've set it yourself. Therefore, the internal working set the content length automatically. This also means, to set it to "0", you need to set the entity to null.

Answer (score 0):

If you are adopting the XML configuration answer by John Rix, make sure to add  a `depends-on` attribute to the `httpClient` bean so the `RemoveSoapHeadersInterceptor` interceptor is added to the `ClientBuilder` **before** the `httpClient` bean gets created. SOAP headers removal hasn't taken effect until I have done so.

```
<bean id="httpClient" factory-bean="httpClientBuilder" factory-method="build" depends-on="interceptedHttpClientBuilder"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

@John Rix's answer
This code helped solved the problem

```
    private static class ContentLengthHeaderRemover implements HttpRequestInterceptor{
            @Override
            public void process(HttpRequest request, HttpContext context) throws HttpException, IOException {
                request.removeHeaders(HTTP.CONTENT_LEN);// fighting org.apache.http.protocol.RequestContent's ProtocolException("Content-Length header already present");
            }
        }
HttpClient client = HttpClients.custom()
                .addInterceptorFirst(new ContentLengthHeaderRemover())
                .build();
```

Comment: This is a copy of igor.zh's answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/24089650/193705