# HttpComponentMessageSender NTLM

Tags: java, spring, apache-httpcomponents

Today I was trying to configure the `HttpComponentsMessageSender` which uses Apache's `org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient` library. Before I used the standard Java classes (I think `java.net.HttpUrlMessageSender` or something along those lines).

My HTTP methods need to authenticate using NTLM and the software is running under Linux so I cannot use the default Windows mechanism to do authentication, but instead I must configure authentication inside the Java application.

Originally I was just using a custom implementation of `java.net.Authenticator` which I used to set the username and password
for the NTLM access. But when I switched to `HttpComponentsMessageSender` this approach did not work anymore. When I tried to setup a custom `HttpClient` configuration with the `HttpComponentsMessageSender` I ran into various issues which I thought I would document here.

I am going to post my own answer but if anyone has a better solution, please feel free to add your solution.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this adding a custom build `HttpClient` object which I built with the `HttpClientBuilder`. However adding this caused the following exception to appear:

> org.apache.http.ProtocolException: Content-Length header already present

1. The solution which I found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24089650/474034) was to add a `HttpRequestInterceptor`.
2. Using the `setConnectionTimeout` on the `HttpComponentsMessageSender` did not work anymore with my custom `HttpClient` object. Instead I had to inject a `RequestConfig` object into the `HttpClientBuilder`.
3. The `NTCredentials` object required the domain name as a parameters. Earlier when I was using the `Authenticator` interface from `java.net` it was enough to just supply the username and password.

This is the code I am using currently:

```
HttpComponentsMessageSender messageSender = new HttpComponentsMessageSender ();
AuthScope authscope;
NTCredentials credentials;
CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider;
Registry<AuthSchemeProvider> registry;
RequestConfig requestConfig;

authscope = new AuthScope (HOST_IP, HOST_PORT);

credentials = new NTCredentials ("user", "pass", null, "domain");

credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider ();

credentialsProvider.setCredentials (authscope, credentials);

registry = RegistryBuilder.<AuthSchemeProvider>create ()
        .register(AuthSchemes.NTLM, new NTLMSchemeFactory ())
        .build ();

HttpRequestInterceptor interceptor
        = (request, context) -> request.removeHeaders(HTTP.CONTENT_LEN);

requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom ()
                             .setConnectTimeout (3000)
                             .build ();

HttpClient httpClient
    =  HttpClientBuilder.create ()
                        .setDefaultRequestConfig (requestConfig)
                        .setDefaultAuthSchemeRegistry (registry)
                        .setDefaultCredentialsProvider (credentialsProvider)
                        .addInterceptorFirst (interceptor)
                        .build ();

messageSender.setHttpClient (httpClient);
```